# How do I update all entries in MySQL table that have a foreign key matching my insert?

Tags: mysql

I have a db with a foreign key (that auto-increments) and an "active" flag, and when I insert a new entry, I want to update the active flag to 0 for all entries with a foreign key matching my insert. So if my table looks like this:

```
primary_key | foreign_key | data_string | active
500           1             "jacob"       1
501           2             "david"       1
```

I want to insert `INSERT INTO mytable (foreign_key, data_string, active) VALUES (1, "vincent", 1)` and get the result:

```
primary_key | foreign_key | data_string | active
500           1             "jacob"       0
501           2             "david"       1
502           1             "vincent"     1
```

I'm familiar with `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but I'd like to use that with my foreign rather than primary key.

Comment: Use stored procedure instead of single inserting query. PS. For this scheme active record within the group by `foreign _key` is always the record with greatest `primary_key` - it seems that `active` column is excess at all.

Comment: A stored procedure or trigger is the way to go, but if you can't for some reason you can also use a transaction to achieve this in multiple queries.

Comment: @doublesharp Row inserting must affect another row of **the same table** - trigger CANNOT be applied.

Comment: From a relational standpoint, a proper solution would be to add a column to your parent table that contains the active record (e.g. the parent table would contain `1, 502`and `2,501` after the insert), otherwise you are duplicating data (having a "1" somewhere already implies "0" somewhere else, but you store this 0 there). You can use a trigger to update that field when you insert/delete data.